# Determining an Interval such that f(x) contracts

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Question: Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a>b>0$. Find an Interval D $\subset \mathbb{R_+}$ such that $f: \mathbb{R_+}\to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)= \sqrt {a+\frac bx}$ contracts for $f_{|D}$. First off I computed the Derivative: $$f'(x)= \frac {-b}{2\sqrt{a+ \frac bx}\ *x^2}$$ Next step I tried to find where $\vert f'(x)\vert=1 \ $. Since $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \uparrow 0$, I specifically tried to find the case where $f'(x)=-1$. This way I can use the mean value theorem to determine from where on the function contracts. Sadly this is where I get stuck. No matter how I rewrite or simplify the function, I cannot seem to solve it for $x$. Is there any merit to this approach, or am I overlooking something here? If yes I'd be very grateful for a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Can you clarify your question/goal ! You wish to find $D$ such that WHAT? And what do you mean $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \uparrow 0$?

Comment: @Leon I wish to find an Intervall $D$ such that my function $f$ is a contraction on my Interval $D$. With $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \uparrow 0$ i mean, that $f'(x)$ approaches the zero from below. The derivative is strictly negative, but tends towards zero from the negative.

Comment: Thank you for your clrification! When you mention the "contraction" do you mean the "Contraction mapping" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that

> If $f'$ is bounded by $1$ on $D$ then $f$ is contractive on $D$.

Thus, we may choose any set $D$ such that $f'$ is bounded by $1$ on $D$.

In your setting, $f'$ is continuous and smooth on $A=(-\infty, -\frac{b}{a}) \cup( 0,+\infty)$ with limits:

- $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} f'(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} f'(x)= 0$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow (-\frac{b}{a})^-} f'(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} f'(x)=+\infty $

Thus, we may choose, for example, $D=[x_0,+\infty)$ where $x_0$ is large enough.

---

**Edit.** An explicit formular for $D$ is
\begin{align}
D=\left[\sqrt[3]{\frac{b}{4}}, +\infty\right)
\end{align}

**Proof.**
Observe that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{|f'(x)|} =2\sqrt{ \frac{a}{b}+ \frac{1}{x} } \frac{x^2}{b^{1/2}}>
2\frac{x^{3/2}}{b^{1/2}}\geq 1
\end{align}
whenever
\begin{align}
x\geq \sqrt[3]{\frac{b}{4}}.
\end{align}

Comment: $f(x)=2x$ has bounded derivative but is not contractive

Comment: @lhf contractive=Lipchitz?

Comment: contractive=Lipchitz with Lipchitz constant less than 1. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping

Comment: @lhf ok, thank you I will modify my answer right now!

Comment: Why is it that that boundedness of $f'$ implies that $f$ is contractive on $D$ ? I can understand the case where $f' \lt 1$ but how can it be for any bounded derivative? If I were to take any $a,b \in \mathbb{R_+}$ I can find an Interval close to zero such that f isn't a contraction.

Comment: @Carlo, ah ok you want to find an explicit formula for $D$ depending on $a$ and $b$ right?

Comment: @Leon Yes! That would be marvelous, if possible

Comment: @Carlo I have proposed  such formula for $D$.

Comment: @Leon Thank you very much, that is an elegant proof.

Comment: @Carlo You're welcome!